# ASP.NET Core api project 3.1 publish on IIS

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, iis

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core API project in my pc local IIS Server using Web Deploy feature in Visual Studio 2019.

I can call all api successfully from local IIS Server.

When I publish to Remote Server and Call the apis, It shows **HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure** error.

1. I have checked applications.json file for invalid attributes.
2. I have installed web hosting bundle from
   https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

[api call from web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCzVP.png)

**In ProjectController.cs**

---

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Testing")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserList()
{
    try
    {
        List<PatientName> lstPAtientName = new List<PatientName>();
        lstPAtientName.Add(new PatientName() { PName = "ABC" });
        lstPAtientName.Add(new PatientName() { PName = "XYZ" });

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict.Add("PatientList", lstPAtientName);

        return Ok(dict);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

---

**In Startup.cs**

---

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

        //Configure CORS also to make this API enable for other application
        services.AddCors(option => option.AddPolicy("MyBlogPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        
        }));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
        services.AddScoped<ProjectRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        //Configure CORS also to make this API enable for other application
        app.UseCors("MyBlogPolicy");

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }

}
```

---

I have set **stdoutLogEnabled="true"** . Website/Logs shows as below.
**

```
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'S' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. LineNumber: 21 | BytePositionInLine: 61.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeStringAndValidate(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Int32 idx)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeString()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8JsonSpan, Utf8JsonReader reader, MetadataDb& database, StackRowStack& stack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 utf8Json, JsonReaderOptions readerOptions, Byte[] extraRentedBytes)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(String json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.ParseStream(Stream input)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Website.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:Website\Program.cs:line 12
```

**

Comment: Do you have multiple appSettings.json for different environments? Check those. It's seems like you fail at parsing some JSON file.  _'S' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. LineNumber: 21_

Comment: It is obvious from the error that there are characters in the JSON file that have escape problems, on line 21 of the file, if you still can’t solve your problem, please post your json file and I will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

In your `.csproj` file?

Check the resources here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: yes, I have added AspNetCoreHostingModel tag in .csproj file. but it is showing same error. also tried to add .UseIISIntegration() in program.cs in published file.

Comment: Could you add your appsettings.json to your question?